# Office 365 Hybrid Mailflow

Tags: email, outlook, office365, exchange-server

i want to use Office 365 / Exchange Online in hybrid with on-prem Mailrelay.
The Mailflow is very confusing, what is best practice?

```
Incoming:
WWWW -> Thirt-Party MTA -> Exchange Hybrid (on-prem) -> Exchange Online (cloud) -> Cloud Mailboxes
WWWW -> Thirt-Party MTA -> Exchange Hybrid (on-prem) -> Outlook
```

I am not sure if A or B is the best practice.

```
Outgoing:
Outlook -> Exchange Hybrid (on-prem) -> Thirt-Party MTA -> Exchange Online (cloud) -> Cloud Mailboxes
A) Outlook -> Exchange Hybrid (on-prem) -> Thirt-Party MTA -> Exchange Online (cloud) -> External Mailboxes
B) Outlook -> Exchange Hybrid (on-prem) -> Thirt-Party MTA -> External Mailboxes
```

I also read that its not possible to have a Thirt-Party MTA beetween Exchange Hybrid and Exchange Online is that true?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Third-party MTA:**
Only Exchange Edge is supported as SMTP gateway for Exchange onprem <-> Exchange online hybrid traffic.

Flow direction:
For simplicity you should either use centralized mail transport or non-centralized mail transport.

**Centralized mail transport (Inbound and Outbound via Exchange onprem)**

Inbound: Internet -> SMTP gateway (third-party MTA is ok) -> Exchange Hybrid -> Onprem mailboxes
Inbound: Internet -> SMTP gateway (third-party MTA is ok) -> Exchange Hybrid -> Hybrid SMTP connector (direct or via Edge) -> Online mailboxes

Outbound: Onprem mailboxes -> Exchange Hybrid -> SMTP gateway (third-party MTA is OK) -> Internet
Outbound: Online mailboxes -> DHybrid SMTP connector (Direct or via Edge) -> Exchange Hybrid -> SMTP gateway (third-party MTA is ok) -> Internet.

The key is that the SMTP traffic between Exchange Online and the Exchange onprem server should either be direct or via exchange edge.

**Non-centralized mail transport (inbound and outbound to internet via Office 365)**

Inbound: Internet -> Exchange Online -> Online mailboxes
Inbound: Internet -> Exchange Online -> Hybrid SMTP connector -> Exchange Hybrid -> Onprem mailboxes

Outbound: Online mailboxes -> Exchange Online -> Internet
Outbound: Onprem mailboxes -> Exchange Hybrid -> Hybrid SMTP connector (either direct or via Exchange Edge) -> Exchange Online -> Internet

Comment: thx. do you also know how to realize high availibility? deploy 2 Exchange Hybrids with its own connector? exchange online does load balancing per default?

Comment: Yes, you can have multiple exchange servers for redundancy and HA. Remember that a Hybrid server is a standard mailbox server. The Hybrid is only a configuration within the exchange environment. So when you configure hybrid via the Hybrid Wizard you will be able to select which exchange servers should handle inbound and outbound SMTP traffic. Also the EWS endpoint that you select like mail.contoso.com could be the standard published loadbalanced endpoint for your Exchange environment. It does not need to be a dedicated namespace for a single "Hybridserver".